# Nested routes and multiple components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I try to create a view in Angular 2 that should look like this:

```
releases-component
-----------------    -------------    --------------
| releases-list |    | rcs-list  |    | binaries-  |
| * release1    |    | * rc1     |    | list       |
|   release2    |    |   rc2     |    |            |
-----------------    -------------    --------------
```

where each of the three parts is a component, whereas `releases` and `rcs` contains a list with links that should map to the following routes:

- `releases` -> list all releases in the `releases` component
- `releases/:id/rcs` -> lists rcs for the release with id in the `rcs` component
- `releases/:id/rcs/:no/binaries` -> lists binaries of the choosen `rc` in the `binaries` component

**releases-component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="rcs"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="binaries"></router-outlet>
```

**routes**

```
{
  path: 'releases',
  component: ReleasesComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', component: ReleasesListComponent },
    {
      path: ':id/rcs',
      outlet: 'rcs',
      component: CandidateComponent,
      children: [
        { path: ':no/binaries', outlet: 'binaries', component: BinariesComponent }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

**releases links** - to show list of rcs

```
{outlets: {rcs: release.id + '/rcs'}}
```

**rcs links** - to show list of binaries

```
{outlets: {binaries: rc.id + '/binaries'}}
```

I have tried all different kind of route and link definitions, but I can't get it to work. With this current solution the binaries simply do not get displayed and after clicking another `rcs` link I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
```

Answer (score 1):

This might sound ridiculously complex. But it's fairly simple. I suggest you have your routing like this:

```
{ path: 'releases', component: ReleaseListComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: NotSelectedComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: ReleaseDetailsComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: NotSelectedComponent },
        { path: 'rcs', component: RcsListComponent, children: [
            { path: '', component: NotSelectedComponent },
            { path: ':id', component: RcsDetailsComponent, children: [
                { path: '', component: NotSelectedComponent },
                { path: 'binaries', component: BinaryListComponent }
            ] }
        ] }
    ] }
] }
```

Now for each path that has a component with children on it, you'll have to place a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. And then it will figure out the rest on it's own.

So, by that I mean that following components will have a `router-outlet` inside their templates:

- `ReleaseListComponent`
- `ReleaseDetailsComponent`
- `RcsListComponent`
- `RcsDetailsComponent`

I wish I could style this to show you on the screen. But that's too much of effort and I would literally be spoon-feeding you in that case.

But here's how it will look on the UI:

[image]

Comment: Thank your, but with this approach I cannot use a predefined layout that only gets updated with the actual data, e.g. I cannot have a heading for the next list until I choose an entry of the previous one.